# Cordova Compass API is giving error code 3

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, compass

This question is already asked on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642057/cordova-compass-api-navigator-compass-watchheading-not-working-error-code-3) but I didn't found any answer to it, so I raised again this. Please can anyone able reply for this?

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Compass Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() 
{
    navigator.compass.getCurrentHeading(onSuccess, onError);
}

function onSuccess(heading)
 {
    alert('Heading: ' + heading.magneticHeading);
}

function onError(compassError) 
{
    alert('Compass Error: ' + compassError.code);
}

</script>
  </head>
 <body>
<h1>Example</h1>
<p>getCurrentHeading</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can inform you about the error, I don't know the solution. `public static int ERROR_FAILED_TO_START = 3;`

Comment: On what kind of device are you running the code sample that's show in the original question?

Comment: I am using android device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either your device does not have a magnetic sensor, or the vendor has not implemented support for it in the OS.

Looking at the Android source code for the device-orientation plugin, the startup code is written like this (modified for brevity):

```
List<Sensor> list = this.sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);

// If found, then register as listener
if (list != null)
    this.setStatus(CompassListener.STARTING);

// If error, then set status to error
else
    this.setStatus(CompassListener.ERROR_FAILED_TO_START);
```

Not sure why they made up their own error code there (`public static int ERROR_FAILED_TO_START = 3`), but really they should be reporting `COMPASS_NOT_SUPPORTED` as defined in the documentation.