# How to get device orientation correctly after main plugin deprecation

Tags: ionic-framework, device-orientation

I need to get the device orientation to make some kind of compass. I saw that the [old plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device-orientation) | [[2]](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation) used for this is now deprecated and that is suggested to use the [W3C Device Orientation API](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-orientation-event-20160818/) now.

I tried to use it this way:

```js
this.window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
}, true);
```

but the main orientation values (alpha, beta and gamma) are always null. I tried to turn on the GPS too see if anything changes, but does not.

I tried [other events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event) related to changes of orientation, but these don't even fire, I belive this is because the orientation values are always null.

```js
this.window.addEventListener("orientationchange", (event) => {
    console.log(event, screen.orientation.angle);                       
}, true);

this.window.onorientationchange = (event) => { 
    console.log(event, screen.orientation.angle);
};
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there other easier or correct way to get these informations?

Comment: Well, I tried to use the deprecated plugin anyway and it gives me error code 3 when I try to use. [Checking the docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-orientation/blob/master/src/android/CompassListener.java#L180) I can see that it's because the plugin can't find the magnetic sensor of my device. 

So, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29062279/7123439), either my device does not have a magnetic sensor, or the vendor has not implemented support for it in the OS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem occurs because my device does not support magnetic sensor (Samsung Galaxy E5)